# How to use PickerView values as the starting number for a Timer to countdown from

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to mimic Apple's timer by allowing the user to select hours, minutes, and seconds and then counting down using a label.

Here is what my storyboard looks like:
[image]

And here is my code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  pickerViewExample
//
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minuteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hourPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var minutePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPicker: UIPickerView!
    var hours = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"]
    var minutes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"]
    var seconds = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pic: UILabel!
    
    var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 15 // this is the problem, I want the 3 PickerView's values
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hourPicker.dataSource = self
        self.hourPicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.minutePicker.dataSource = self
        self.minutePicker.delegate = self
        
        self.secondPicker.dataSource = self
        self.secondPicker.delegate = self
    

        
    }
    
    @IBAction func fireTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @objc func timerAction() {
        if (counter > 0) {
            counter -= 1
            countDownLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    // data source method
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // data source method
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView == hourPicker) {
            return hours.count
        }
        if (pickerView == minutePicker) {
            return minutes.count
        }
        if (pickerView == secondPicker) {
            return seconds.count
        }
        return 20;
    }
  
    // delegate method
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView == hourPicker) {
            return hours[row]
        }
        if (pickerView == minutePicker) {
            return minutes[row]
        }
        if (pickerView == secondPicker) {
            return seconds[row]
        }
        return "NIL";
    }
    
    // delegate method
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if (pickerView == hourPicker) {
            print(hourPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0).description)
            hourLabel.text = hours[row]
        }
        if (pickerView == minutePicker) {
            print(minutePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0).description)
            minuteLabel.text = minutes[row]
        }
        if (pickerView == secondPicker) {
            print(secondPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0).description)
            secondLabel.text = seconds[row]
        }
        
    }

}
```

I am able to get the data from each of the PickerViews, the hours, minutes, and seconds selected. The 3 labels take on that value from each respective PickerView value.

How can I use these values so that the `Timer()` can count down from it? I cannot declare the `count` as a global variable AND have it take on the value's of each of the PickerViews.

What I want is `counter` to be equal to `value in the Hours PickerView * 60 * 60` + `value in Minutes PickerView * 60` + `Value in Seconds PickerView` and have the Timer count down from there.

Comment: When you click the start button, just get the `selectedRow` for each picker; Multiply hours by 3600 and minutes by 60 and add those two values to the seconds picker and there is your time in seconds.  By the way, you can use a single picker with three components rather than three pickers. Also that isn't the best way to run a timer.  See [my article](https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f) - It deals with counting up, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: @Paulw11 but I am having trouble telling the timer to count down from that number.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to?  Use that general approach - Calculate the duration and then add that number of seconds to "Now" to get a target `Date` - `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:duration)`. Save that in a property.  Then every time your timer ticks you can compare that date against now to work out how much time is remaining and whether the time is up.